# Cannot connect to the database Postgres Docker Container from other Container

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, go, docker-multi-stage-build

I have a service in a Docker Container, which synchronies Data from an another DB to my DB and the Sync-Container can't get a connection to the Postgres DB Container.

The Containers
[image: It restarts because it exits after every connection failure]

My Error-Message

```
Cannot connect to the database, exiting now: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5432: connect: connection refused"
```

I can connect to the DB via TablePlus on 127.0.0.1:5432 but via Docker Inspect is
[image: Docker Inspect on IP Adress]

The Sync-Service is Written in Go - Database Name, User and Password are the same as I connected via TablePlus. I also tried the IPs `0.0.0.0` and the `172.19.0.2`.

Does anyone have any idea why its not connecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try connecting to postgres:5432

You need to use container name when connecting from another docker container